# How to kill PHP session on browser close

Tags: php, session, cookies

This returns '0'

```
ini_get("session.cookie_lifetime");
```

However when I close and reopen my browser, the session variables remain there.

I have tried several browsers and have the same problem on each.

How do I ensure that the session cookie is eliminated when the browser is closed?

Comment: Make sure you do the ini_get at the point where the session cookie would be first set. Testing later on is somewhat pointless, because various overrides could have changed the conditions that existed when the cookie was created.

Comment: None of those suggestions work. How do I completely clear the session by closing the browser? It works if I run session_unset() but most people will just simply close their browser. I need to completely kill the session just by closing the browser. How do I do that?